# XML Parsing getting id

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to get all id's from this url and display in uitableview "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/".

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/"];

        NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

        xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:xmlString];


        NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", xmlDoc);



    }


    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [xmlDoc count];
    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellID = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

        if (cell == nil) {

            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
        }


        cell.textLabel.text = [[[xmlDoc objectForKey:@"CUSTOMER"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"__text"];


        return cell;

    }
```

I am getting only 0,1,2 values displayed in uitableview and ignoring the remaining id's ?

Comment: Can you please show us, what you have tried yet?

Comment: I tried to follow a xml tutorial which is very much similar to http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xmlparsing-with-nsxmlparser-tutorial but end up displaying nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Library to convert `XMLData` into `NSDictionary` object.
https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary then simply fetch your required data from `NSDictionary` object and update it into your `TableView`.

Comment: I am getting only 0,1,2 values displayed in uitableview and ignoring the remaining id's ?

Comment: Please share your code so that i can find bug and tell you.

Comment: You may be get those 123 only because in NumberOfRows you were returning the count of objects in your xmlDoc object which may be 3 but you need to give the count of the array which you were getting inside the customer object in xmlDoc.

Comment: I have edited my question.that's the code i have written ? is there anything i m missing ?

Comment: Thanks. Its Working.